# Customize spinner dialog: popupbackground setting for dialog

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner as shown below. While I can style the row("raspberrypi-0"), I am unable to change anything for the rest of the dialog.

I would like to change the popup background color. If possible the color of "Select a device for the sensor" should also be changed. Below is my spinner's xml defined inside a linear layout(not shown).

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    android:id="@+id/attached_device_value_dropdown"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    app:ms_alignLabels="false"
    app:ms_arrowSize="@dimen/spinner_arrow_size"
    app:ms_hint="@string/attached_device_select"
    app:ms_enableErrorLabel="true"
    app:ms_multiline="true"
    app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/black"
    app:ms_hintColor="@color/light_grey"
    app:ms_baseColor="@color/black"
    app:ms_highlightColor="@color/black"
    app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"/>
```

A similar setting: `popupBackground` exist when one sets spinner mode to "dropdown". I am looking for something similar to this but for dialog.

In Java, this is how I set my spinner:

```
CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(parentActivity, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, devices);
customArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
registeredDevicesDropdown.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);
```

where `spinner_dropdown_item` is just a text view.

Also MaterialSpinner just extends Spinner, so most of the things should apply. [Here](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner) is more info about it on github.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by hacking the adapter code for the MaterialSpinner. In your overridden `getCustomView` function, set the color for background and text.

```
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, boolean isDropDownView) {
    //TODO: use convert view.
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final int resid = isDropDownView ? android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item : android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item;
    TextView row = (TextView) inflater.inflate(resid, parent, false);
    row.setText(devices.get(position).getDeviceLabel());

    //Hack: Cannot set the dialogs color from XML and text color from XML                                                          
    row.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(parentActivity, R.color.black));        //set Text Color for the row content
    parent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(parentActivity, R.color.colorSecondary));      //set backgraound color ofr skeleton.
    return row;
}
```